# SQL Server - Arranging select query results by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following query (and several other very similar ones) which gathers volumes of data (in this case calls) and then arranges it by month.

It works fine and outputs the results I need, but I have a feeling there must be a more practical/shorter way of doing this:

```
SELECT
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JAN',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'FEB',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MAR',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'APR',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MAY',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JUN',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JUL',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AUG',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'SEP',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OCT',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NOV',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DEC'

 FROM [Telephony].[dbo].[tbl_Outbound]

 WHERE source like '132%'
       and duration > 300

   union all

SELECT
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JAN',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'FEB',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MAR',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'APR',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MAY',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JUN',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'JUL',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AUG',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'SEP',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OCT',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NOV',
 sum(case when datepart(mm,calldate) = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DEC'

  FROM [Telephony].[dbo].[tbl_Outbound]

  WHERE source like '132%'
```

Thanks for any tips you can give :)

Comment: You really don't care if the calldate was in 2014 or 2013?

Comment: This is pretty verbose, but the verbosity seems to be due to the need for a crosstab/pivot style output and less so on the month counting. You could do this all in one query without the union, but it would be just as ugly looking.

Comment: Lamak - This table only contains 12 months of rolling data so in this case no

Comment: JNevill - The need for this format is because I just have this query as a data connection in excel, so the data comes out in the format I need as I have several of these queries that populate one data sheet.

Comment: @Uberzen1 I [rejected your attempted edit of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6057189); if you wish to change the intent/functionality of an answer, please add a comment instead of editing directly. Edits should only be for revising/improving the answer, without changing the intent.

Comment: @admdrew my edit did not change the intent, it just made it so it actually runs, adding a missed comma and a group by clause, which replicates perfectly the results I was getting with my own query above.

Comment: @Uberzen1 While it may seem like a minor change, adding `group by` does indeed change the intent of a SQL query answer. Feel free to add a comment to the answer indicating what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following would work. This uses SQL Server's Pivot Functionality:

```
SELECT rowName,[January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December] 
FROM (
    SELECT
        "Duration>300" as rowName,
        datename(month, calldate) as MonthName,
        Count(*) as recordCount

    FROM
        [Telephony].[dbo].[tbl_Outbound]
    WHERE source like '132%'
        and duration > 300
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        "AllDurations" as rowName,
        datename(month, calldate) as MonthName,
        Count(*) as recordCount

    FROM
        [Telephony].[dbo].[tbl_Outbound]
    WHERE source like '132%'
) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    Sum(recordCount)
    FOR MonthName in ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could do that, this is very helpful indeed!

Comment: All I did to tweak this was add in a group by calldate and also add a missing comma after rowName

Comment: Thats not bad for not having a server to test this on!